# What is the correct order to validate parameters?

Tags: c#, exception, theory

For reference, I would like to note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157139/what-is-the-correct-way-to-validate-the-arguments-of-a-constructor) is taken into consideration for **how** the prarameters are tested.

Lets take the following two snippets as an example:

```
public void DoSomething1(Dictionary<string, string> param1, Object param2)
{
    if (null == param1)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
    if(!param1.Keys.Contains("somekey"))
        throw new ArgumentException("param1 must contain key \"somekey\"");
    if(null == param2)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("param2");

    // now we do some stuff
}

public void DoSomething2(Dictionary<string, string> param1, Object param2)
{
    if (null == param1)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
    if (null == param2)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("param2");
    if(!param1.Keys.Contains("somekey"))
        throw new ArgumentException("param1 must contain key \"somekey\"");  

    // now we do some stuff
}
```

Both methods will accomplish the same protection to the inner workings of the method.

**My Question Is...**

What is the correct approach / order to test parameters passed to a method (such as in this example) **and why**?

**Please cite references to backup your answer.**

Comment: I don't think there is a "correct approach" to this. In this case it really looks like a matter of preference.

Comment: The correct approach is the one that makes sense. For example, the null exception on param1 should be checked first, before you call `Contains()` on it, just like you are doing in your code sample.

Comment: I understand both work; should you completely validate param1 before validating param2?  Or should you progress from the simplest to more complex exceptions within your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "correct order".

It's completely implementation specific.  In other words is it more important to you to report back that the parameters are null OR is it more important to do deep inspection of the parameters as you get to them?

If I was doing this I would take the "performance" approach.  In other words I would first test that all necessary parameters were non null, then I would open up each parameter to make sure I got what I wanted.  It's faster (slightly) to do the null reference checks than it is to test whether a dictionary contains a key.

Of course, the only time I'd even worry about it is if this method was destined to be called hundreds of times a second and it had a likelihood of being passed null parameters.  For methods that have limited impact I would stick with what the caller needed to know first.

Comment: I am under the same opinnion as you.  However, is it fair to establish a "best practice" of testin via performance in *all* cases?

Comment: @davids: No.  There are numerous things we can do to code to make it perform better.  However, highly performant code can lead to less readable code.  From that perspective you have to go on a case by case basis to determine whether performance is more highly desired than readability.

Comment: Another reason is that the performance difference of code written one way versus another can either be trivial or of zero consequence to the execution of the application.  For example, if the code in your example is executed at most once an hour then it makes zero sense to optimize it in this way.  However, if it is executed hundreds or thousands a time a second then the difference between highly optimized and unoptimized might actually have a financial impact on the hardware necessary to meet performance goals.  Which is why the common best practice is to optimize only when necessary.